# Custom file type/MIME Type in Google Picker?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, mime-types, picker, google-drive-picker

I am trying to use [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) to pick a file from user's Google Drive. My app supports `xml` and `graph` file. For xml, it's simple enough. However, now for custom `.graph` file, I cannot in anyway shows it. I tried:

```
view.setMimeTypes("text/xml,text/graph,application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.graph,.graph");
```

- text/graph
- application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.graph
- .graph

But only xml files show up. I tried inspecting the MIME-type of my file, and the MIME type is `application/octet-stream`. If I add that to the list, the `.graph` file shows up. But it's too general, other binary files show up too.

Is there a way to show custom file types on Google Picker?

Comment: try `View.setQuery(string)` where string is defined at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

Comment: I want to refer the solution from this SO post on how to [Open a Specific Mimetypes with Google Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901668/opening-specific-mimetypes-with-google-picker). You could use the code as follows: `REALTIME_MIMETYPE = 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.'+appID;`, then set this to `view.setMimeTypes` method: view.setMimeTypes(REALTIME_MIMETYPE);